# How to remove AdMob completely from Android Studio project?

Tags: android-studio, admob

Probably I'm asking a too much simple question but I didn't find any exact answer by googling.

In my android studio project, How to remove AdMob completely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the dependency for Google's Mobile Ads SDK is usually `play-services-ads` or `firebase-ads` if you're using Firebase. I'd remove whichever one of those is present in your `build.gradle` file's dependencies section, and then remove any references from your Java/Kotlin files that no longer resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you download the library it might happen that it creates an exception or it is not implemented properly or not downloaded properly in this condition it is better to remove them completely.

You can search for "edit library and dependency.." inside that you will find a lot of liberals and the one which you want delete you can select it and press delete key.